# How can I query relational active record from table B with table A has two fields connect the table B's primary key?

Tags: mysql

Everyone.

I need to query a exchange rule records for my application, and the rule table like this:

[image]

and has another table like this:

[image]

And I need to get the data structure like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0] => array(6) {
    ["id"] => int(4)
    ["pay_goods"] => [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "小熊",
        "alias" => "littlebear",
        "img_url" => "xxxx",
        "desc" => "xxxxxx",
        ...
    ],
    ["goal_goods"] => [
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "红钻",
        "alias" => "reddiamond",
        "img_url" => "xxxx",
        "desc" => "xxxxxx",
        ...
    ],
    ["exchange_ratio"] => string(8) "1:985000"
    ["is_del"] => int(0)
    ["order"] => int(4)
  },
  [1] => array(6) {
     ...
  },
  ...
```

How can I query out this result with one SQL sentence?

Thought for a long time and I cannt find the SQL, Please Help M

Comment: *"How can I query out this result with one SQL sentence?"* You would need to use a `INNER JOIN` in SQL .. But still you would need PHP code to "pack" the SQL results into the expected PHP array.

Comment: I can use "foreach" but It will increase other 8 times query,  I want less query times, so I Want find a efficient way to do this task...^0^~~~

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Avoid non-English text here, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this situation in PHP Model Relationship And Thanks!

```
public function getExchangeGoodsList() {
    $gameGoodsConfigModel = new GameGoodsConfigModel();
    $config = $gameGoodsConfigModel::all();
    $goodsExchangeRuleList = [];
    foreach ($config as $key => $obj) {
        $itemArr = module_to_array($obj);
        $itemArr['pay_goods'] = module_to_array($obj->goods);
        $itemArr['goal_goods'] = module_to_array($obj->goalGoods);
        array_push($goodsExchangeRuleList, $itemArr);
    }
}
```